# My codes stop working when in the same file

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with my Javascript code. It is in dutch though so you might have to translate. The "Rente" code is working and is showing an alert when asked to do so. But, when I add the "BTW" code they both won't show an alert box or even do the formula. Like they are crossing eachother but I can't find it. The "BTW" code also doesn't work alone. After i followed a view tips of you guys it still isn't working.

here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SEAopdracht.css">
    <title>MuTan Inc.</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function laatZien(divID)  {
    var Home = document.getElementById("Home");
    var BTW = document.getElementById("BTW");
    var Rente = document.getElementById("Rente");
    var directie = document.getElementById("directie");

    var item = document.getElementById(divID);

    if (item.id == "Home"){      
    Home.className="zichtbaar";      
    BTW.className="verstopt";      
    Rente.className="verstopt";
    directie.className="verstopt";     
    }

    if (item.id == "BTW"){      
    Home.className="verstopt";      
    BTW.className="zichtbaar";      
    Rente.className="verstopt";
    directie.className="verstopt";    
    }

    if (item.id == "Rente"){      
    Home.className="verstopt";      
    BTW.className="verstopt";      
    Rente.className="zichtbaar";
    directie.className="verstopt";
    }

    if (item.id == "directie"){      
    Home.className="verstopt";      
    BTW.className="verstopt";      
    Rente.className="verstopt";
    directie.className="zichtbaar";
      }
     }
    </script>
 </head>

    <body>

      <div id="bovenste">
        <h1> <img src="logo.png" width=250></h1>
      </div>


      <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BTW berekenen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rente bereken</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">De directie</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="inhoud">

  <div id="Home" class="zichtbaar">
    <img src="logo.png"> <br>
    <h2>Welkom op onze Website! <br>
    Wij hebben er hier voor gezorgd dat u GRATIS uw BTW én Rente kan bereken.<br>
    Met de kennis die wij hebben opgedaan hebben we samen deze website in elkaar gezet! <br>
    Wij hopen dat onze website u helpt om gemakkelijker u BTW en Rente te bereken!<br>
    Heeft u klachten kunt u ons GEEN bericht sturen naar GEEN e-mailadres.<br>
    Groetjes, <br>
    Natan en Muhammed </h2><br>
  </div>

  <div id="BTW" class="verstopt">

   <script type="text/javascript">

   function myFunction() {

   var inclusief = document.document.getElementById('exnaarin').checked
   var exclusief = document.document.getElementById('innaarex').checked

   var nul = document.getElementById(0).checked
   var zes = document.getElementById(6).checked
   var max = document.getElementById(21).checked

   var b = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('Bedrag')[0].value);

   BTW = "Dat zou gelijk staat aan een bedrag van €"
   if (inclusief && nul) {
   BTW += b;
   }
   else if (inclusief && zes) {
   BTW += (((b/100)* 6)+ b);    
   }

   else if (inclusief && max) {
   BTW += (((b/100)* 21)+ b);  
   }

   else if (exclusief && nul) {
   BTW += b;
   }

   else if (exclusief && zes) {
   BTW += ((b/106)*100);
   }

   else if (exclusief && max) {
   BTW += ((b/121)* 100);
   }
   alert(BTW);

  }
   </script>
    <form name= "mijnForm">

    <caption> BTW berekenen </caption><br>
    <br>
    Wat wil je doen?<br>
    <input type="radio" id="exnaarin" name="BTW" value="Naarinclusief" checked>Van exclusief naar inclusief
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="innaarex" name="BTW" value="Naarexclusief">Van inclusief naar exclusief
    <br>
    <br>
    Welk percentate BTW wil je gebruiken?<br>
    <input type="radio" id="0" name="procent" value="0procent" checked>0%
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="6" name="procent" value="6procent" >6%
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="21" name="procent" value="21procent" >21%
    <br>
    <br>
    Over welk bedrag wil je de BTW berekenen?<br>
    <input type ="tekst" name ="Bedrag" value = "" placeholder="Bedrag?">
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="bereken2" value="Bereken!" onClick="myFunction()">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="Rente" class="verstopt">
     <!-- Dit is 1 groot pokkewerk, zou het fijn vinden als je hier niet
     aan zit, liefs Natan-->

     <script type="text/javascript">

        function berekening() {

         var enkel = document.getElementById('Rente1').checked
         var samen = document.getElementById('Rente2').checked

         var x = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('percentage')[0].value);
         var y = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('Geleendbedrag')[0].value);
         var z = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('Hoeveeljaar')[0].value);

         resultaat = "U moet €"
         if (enkel) {
         resultaat +=((z *(x *(y/100))) + y);
         resultaat += " afbetalen."      
         alert(resultaat);
         }


         else if (samen) {
         resultaat1 = "U moet €"
         resultaat1 += y * Math.pow((1 + (x/100)), z);
         resultaat1 += " afbetalen."
         alert(resultaat1);
         }
        }
     </script>
       <form name="mijnForm">
        <table>
            <caption>Rente berekenen</caption>

            <tr>
              <td class="midden kop">Vraag</td>
              <td class="midden kop">Antwoord</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="midden">Welke soort rente moet je betalen?</td>
              <td class="midden">
              <input type="radio" id="Rente1" name="rente" value="enkel" checked>Enkelvoudige rente
              <br>
              <input type="radio" id="Rente2" name="rente" value="samen">Samengestelde rente
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="midden">Hoe hoog is het percentage die betaald moet worden?</td>
              <td class="midden">
              <input type = "tekst" name = "percentage" value = "" placeholder="Percentage?">
              </td>             
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="midden">Welk bedrag heb je geleend?</td>
              <td class="midden">
              <input type = "tekst" name = "Geleendbedrag" value = "" placeholder="Hoeveel geleend?">
              </td>             
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="midden">Hoeveel jaar ga je het bedrag lenen></td>
              <td class="midden">
              <input type = "tekst" name = "Hoeveeljaar" value = "" placeholder="jaaraantal?">
              </td>             
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="midden">Druk op de knop om je rente te berekenen!-----></td>
              <td class="midden">
              <input type="button" name="bereken1" value="Berekenen" onClick="berekening()">
              </td>             
            </tr>
          </table>
         </form>
  </div>

   <div id="directie" class="verstopt">
    <img src="natan.jpg"><br> 
    Dit is Natan, <br>
    één van de makers van deze site! <br>
    Natan is 15 jaar oud. <br>

    <img src="luzacfoto.png">
  </div>

</div>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>

    <li>
      <a href="javascript:laatZien('Home');">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="javascript:laatZien('BTW');">BTW berekenen</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="javascript:laatZien('Rente');">Rente berekenen</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="javascript:laatZien('directie');">De directie</a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>

     </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what does the code should do?

Comment: Lines 87 & 88 - you have `document.document.getElementById` instead of just `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors:

To get the values by id and name in `myFunction()`:

```
var inclusief = document.getElementById('exnaarin').checked
var exclusief = document.getElementById('innaarex').checked

var nul = document.getElementById(0).checked
var zes = document.getElementById(6).checked
var max = document.getElementById(21).checked

var b = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('Bedrag')[0].value);
```

Same in `berekening()`:

```
var enkel = document.getElementById('Rente1').checked
var samen = document.getElementById('Rente2').checked

var x = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('percentage')[0].value);
var y = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('Geleendbedrag')[0].value);
var z = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('Hoeveeljaar')[0].value);
```

See more on MDN [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

Comment: At first thanks for you answer, but something is still not working because it doesn't show a alert box when I click the button. Do you have more tips? full code above^^

Comment: `document.document.getElementById('exnaarin').checked` has to be `document.getElementById('exnaarin').checked`. Same for `exclusief`. Mistake by me, sorry for that.